# How to access a method created in a vsto word ribbon from a new form

Tags: c#, wpf, vsto

/*Hi, I am creating a vsto add-in for word 2010. This add-in contains a button, that when clicked opens a new form for user input (using a couple of textboxes and labels and a button). The theory is that when i click the OK button, the program will take the textbox texts and call a method found in vsto add-in ribbon class. For some reason (I realize this might be a simple mistake, but not sure where I went wrong), I am not able to call the method (found in the vsto ribbon class) using the OK button (problem in referencing it?). The following is a part of the code*/

//CODE FOR RIBBON

```
namespace somenamespace
{
public partial class Ribbon1
{
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Word.Document document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument; }           

//This method is used to replace the generic text with the one that we need 
    //specifically for our document

    public void MyMethod(string TextToReplace, string NewText)
    {
        Word.Find fnd = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Find;

        fnd.ClearFormatting();
        fnd.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        fnd.Forward = true;
        fnd.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;

        fnd.Text = TextToReplace;
        fnd.Replacement.Text = NewText;

        fnd.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
    }

    private void buttonScopingApproval_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

        Info_Scoping info_Scoping = new Info_Scoping();
        info_Scoping.Show();
    }
}
```

//Info_Scoping is the name of the new WPF form that will show for user input, and this is the code for it:

```
namespace moeRibbon
{
public partial class Info_Scoping : Form
{
    public Info_Scoping()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Info_Scoping.ActiveForm.Hide();
        RegNumber = textBox1.Text;
        RegYear = textBox2.Text;
        //I need to access the MyMethod() method created in the ribbon class from here, but intellisense doesn't recognize it.         


    }

    public string RegNumber { get; set; }
    public string RegYear { get; set; }      

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.MyMethod(string, string);
```